# What are tasks inside another task in DevTools profiler?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, profiling

According to the [article](https://web.dev/articles/optimize-long-tasks), long-running tasks can be divided into smaller tasks using `setTimeout` to avoid blocking the main thread.
However, in the DevTools profiler, I sometimes observe tasks grouped into another task, reported as a long-running task.
[image: a task including another tasks]

I tried to break a long-running task using `setTimeout`, but the deferred functions ended up in another long-running task.
What are these "sub-tasks", how are they grouped, and how can they be separated into distinct tasks?

Comment: Looks like a bug in devtools because one setTimeout creates one separate task per the JS specification, there's also no such thing as task grouping in JS. There's a known bug where devtools visually splits a single physical task into multiple bars in the flamechart, i.e. you have a single long-running timer callback.